# IsPostBack asp.net

Tags: asp.net, request, querystring

A minha aplicação asp.net (aspx) possui dois controls do tipo Label que precisam ser preenchidos com informações de um Request QueryString.
Na Page_Load faço o tratamento para que os controls do tipo Label recebam estas informações e na verdade recebem, mas não renderizam, ou seja, não é exibido na página. Fiz um teste colocando constantes no lugar dos valores da Request QueryString e quando faço isso os controls do tipo Label aparecem preenchidos. O que poderia ser isto? Li muita coisa a respeito de ViewState e seus comandos mas nenhum resolveu.

```
insira o código aqui
<asp:Panel ID="panFeedBack" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMarcacao" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>


insira o código aqui
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Request.QueryString.Item("id") Is Nothing Then
        Dim QueryStrMarcacao As String = Request.QueryString.Item("id").Split("|")(1)
        lblMarcacao.Text = "Marcação: " & QueryStrMarcacao
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Poste o seu código, assim fica mais fácil para auxiliar

Answer (score 0):

Tente o código:

```
If Not Request.QueryString("id") Is Nothing Then
     Dim QueryStrMarcacao As String = Request.QueryString("id")
     lblMarcacao.Text = "Marcação: " & QueryStrMarcacao
End If
```

Segue Imagens:
Código VB:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/capturar-png--4018

Código ASP:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/asp-png

Página:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/pagina-png--30

Quanto ao viewstate, é a forma do .net "identificar" o estado da página, por exemplo o "IsPostBack" usado no Page_load, ele identifica caso seja a primeira vez que esteja acessando a página, logo não é um postBack(Reload da página), porém caso utilizado algum item na pagina que gere postBack, exemplo um droDownList que carregue outro, a página gerará um postBack e através dessa identificação será possível você manter o estado dos itens na página

Comment: Segui a sugestão e o mesmo acontece.
Quando uso debug a Label recebe a informação, mas não renderiza no final, ou seja, não mostra na página.

Comment: De uma olhada nas imagens que fiz upload, você chegou a tentar fazer isso em outra página?

Comment: Em outro site onde uso masterpage isso funciona muito bem, mas neste caso específico a única diferença é a página ser um aspx sem masterpage.

Comment: ai complicou rsrs. por fim, tentou deixar sem if? para ver se ao menos a palavra "Marcação" é escrita?

Comment: Se tirar o if  e também qualquer alusão ao Request QueryString a palavra "Marcação" é escrita

Comment: A QueryString é disparada por Javascript
$.post('/Celular.aspx?id=' + param, {});

Comment: Resolvi a questão colocando numa session recebendo params da querystring